# Como fazer a transposição do resultado de uma pesquisa usando SQL Server?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Ou melhor dizendo como fazer com que as colunas do resultado de uma pesquisa **SQL Server**, se tornem linhas do resultado, como se segue nas imagens abaixo:

Um resultado de pesquisa usando a cláusula **select** qualquer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fazer com que o resultado fique da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: Lembrando que eu tenho conhecimento que eu posso fazer isso com UNPIVOT, estou querendo mais soluções as quais eu possa resolver isso.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Utilizando *pivot*. Veja esse [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699997/sql-server-transpose-rows-into-columns) do SO.

Comment: No meu caso eu tenho que usar UNPIVOT, pois eu quero transformar colunas em linhas, e no caso do PIVOT ele transforma linhas em colunas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem 3 maneiras de fazer:

- Union All, Aggregate e case.
- Unpivot and Pivot Static.
- Dynamic Pivot.

Porem em questões de performance, o Pivot e Unpivot são os recomentados, até porque são funções próprios para isso.

Eu poderia dar exemplos, porem é recomendado utilizar o pivot, então deixarei [esse link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql) para apenas curiosidade.

Finalizando, não existe solução simples para fazer isso em SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Tomando como base, onde temos uma tabela Caixa e levando em consideração que queremos mostrar o saldo mês a mês de todos os anos teríamos inicialmente uma consulta que retorna o valor, o mês e o ano

```
select a.Valor, 
    datepart(month, a.DataHora) as Mes, 
    datepart(year, a.DataHora) Ano
from CaixaCorrido a) as Caixa
```

porém nessa consulta o resultado estaria em linhas, para transformar esses resultados em colunas, basta usar o `pivot`, ficando então da seguinte forma

```
select * 
from (
select a.Valor, 
    datepart(month, a.DataHora) as Mes, 
    datepart(year, a.DataHora) Ano
from CaixaCorrido a) as Caixa
pivot
(
    sum(Valor)
    for Mes
    in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) Caixa
```